# Visual Studio 2015 - Automatic round brackets for functions

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for C/C++ development, I'm used to Eclipse where, when I click on a suggested method, it's automatically written (with braces and parameters); currently in visual studio when I select a suggested function it just appears with no braces and no parameters, is there a way to do what I've asked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). If your looking for Visual Studio 2015 to have the run like Eclipse or even Sublime, then take a look at this - also check some [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld7ubGmxL7A) videos about developers who use the software to see if this is what you are looking for.